# Need an Invertible Image Transformation Function such that:

Tags: python, image, opencv, math, image-processing

does there exist an invertible image transformation function ***F*** such that if I apply ***F*** on image ***X*** I get ***Y*** and ***Y*** looks as noisy and random as possible. If I apply blur to ***Y*** to get ***Y**** and then take ***F***<sup>(-1)</sup>***(Y*)*** to get ***X**** then ***X*** and ***X**** should be as similar as possible (like a blur version of ***X***).

I would really appreciate any help that I can get

Comment: What kind of blur ?

Comment: Any kind. Gaussian for example

Comment: What is the purpose of doing that as opposed to just blurring the image?

Comment: @fmw42 some complex cryptography and image processing project

Comment: If you are trying transform an image to garbage and back, and you are not restricted to OpenCV, then see encipher and decipher at ImageMagick. See https://imagemagick.org/www/script/cipher.php and https://imagemagick.org/Usage/transform/#encipher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do this:
1. Calculate the Fourier transform of the image.
2. For each frequency, without changing the amplitude, pseudo-randomly (in a special way) shift the phase.
3. Make the inverse Fourier transform.
We will get a noisy image.
If we filter it, for example, with a Gaussian filter, then we can restore (knowing the pseudorandom phase shift function) the original smoothed image.
I test this idea and write Octave/Matlab code:

```
img=imread('Lena.png');
mag=abs(fft2(img));
ang=angle(fft2(img)); %phase
ns=angle(fft2(rand(size(img))));%phase random matrix
noise=mag.*exp(i*(ang+ns));
noise_img=uint8(abs(ifft2(noise))); %noise image
% add blur
f=fspecial('gaussian', 7, 3); % gaussian filter 7x7
noise_img_gauss=imfilter(noise_img, f); %noise image with gaussian blur
% recovery image
mag=abs(fft2(noise_img_gauss));
ang=angle(fft2(noise_img_gauss));
recov=mag.*exp(i*(ang-ns));
img_recovery=uint8(abs(ifft2(recov)));
imwrite(img_recovery, 'img_recovery.png');
imwrite(noise_img_gauss, 'noise_img_gauss.png');
```

Source, noise image whith blur and recovery image:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: That sounds like a very good idea. As the Gaussian filter preserves the phase (it is real), it will not perturb the phase shift and the restored version will be the original image, Gaussian-blurred.

Comment: FFT would return 2 images. Better to do DCT, which returns only one image.

Comment: I tried FFT, DCT and RFFT but none of them worked as required. Blurring always ruins it

Comment: @fmw42, I think you are right, thank you very much for the idea. DCT would be better.

Comment: @AlexAlex it totally worked. I found a bug in my code and in my concepts. Thank

Answer (score 0):

You can try Wavelet transform, say "Haar" Wavelet transform.

```
F-> Wavelet transform function
X-> input image
Y-> 4 components of F(X). You can take any high-frequency component, say HH
```

If the image is relatively smooth, HH will not have enough energy and thus small blur will not impact much.

The only thing you need to be careful about is that you keep the other 3 components LL, LH, and HL as it is.

Comment: "If the image is relatively smooth": the image is "noisy and random".